# Is there a font similar to this document?

Tags: templates, examples

Here is the document:

[image]

What I am interested in is the fonts

P.S: even if there is no document class that does all of that, I will be interested in sources indicating how to do each of them independently.

Comment: You didn't ask for much... to create what you asked for takes at least a week for me. I'm joking...and welcome to the community of TeX.SE.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks :). One week :O I was panicking, I need to do it quickly for my thesis that's why I am looking for similar classes instead of doing things manually one by one.

Comment: The fonts of the old books not exist. It is necessary to choose a similar font: `urw garamond` for example and a specific similar upright greek.

Comment: @Sebastiano The font is great <3, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You asked, "Is there a document class similar to..."? Short answer: "No". Longer answer: Your query consists of at least 7 separate questions which are not tied intrinsically to any particular LaTeX document class. Moreover, quite a few or your questions cannot be answered definitively without you supplying quite a bit of additional information about the desired document layout. Among the missing pieces of information are the paper size, the height and width of the text block, and the main document font size. Doesn't your school provide a template that satisfies its formatting requirements?

Comment: @Mico, No my school does not have any requirements regarding the size or fonts. The only constraint is that it's an a4paper. Currently I am using the memoir class.

Comment: The `memoir` class is a fine class. In particular, it defines quite a few chapter heading styles; hopefully, one of the predefined styles comes close to meeting your requirements. Quite a few of your formatting requirements -- such as writing out "Chapitre Premier" rather than "Chapitre 1" have come up already on this site; I suggest you spend some time searching the site for such postings.

Comment: @Mico That's what I am doing, for example, I updated the post to include the paragraph numbering.

Comment: The summary paragraph might be something like `\newenvironment{summary}{\begingroup\normalfont\itshape\footnotesize}{\endgroup}`

Comment: A good way to change the section style would be `titlesec`. The font appeaars to be Helvetica, so you might set it with `\sffamily\bfseries\upshape`..

Comment: Programmatically generating French masculine ordinal numbers isn’t tremendously complicated (It’d be easier in Expl3), although it’s non-trivial. It’s basically a list of cases that prepends recursively calls itself on the number mod 10, 20 or 100 and knows about special cases such as *premier*, *vingt-et-unième*, *soixante-et-onzième*, *quatre-vingt-unième*, *cent deuxième*, *deux centième* if you needed it to go that high, etc. Doing it in English would have many fewer special cases.

Answer (score 3):

For the upright characters you can choose

```
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
```

Here there is a short code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}

\begin{document}

$\rho,\epsilon>0$, $\boldsymbol{\rho}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: You're always here! with your brilliant answers!

Comment: @Med-Elf aahahah but it is not true.....however thank you very much to you and all the users of this great community.